# Trying to override templates in FOSUserBundle, but having no effect

Tags: symfony, view, overriding, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to modify the skin of the register.html.twig template found in `FOSUserBundle/Resources/views/Registration/register.html.twig`.

I've basically followed the [instructions in the documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) down to a T.

1. Like it told to do so, I created `/app/Resources/views/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register.html.twig.`
2. Cleared the cache (and browser cache just to be sure)

NO effect! I've put a blank file in register.html.twig, but no matter what I put there, when I go to /register/, I still see the default template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, these things happen all the time.

It should be:

```
/app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register.html.twig
```

[Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates)